# How to tell if a country has states and what the state codes are

Tags: api, geonames

With the help of this community I understood how to find country codes and query geoNames data based on that.

What I am stuck on now is understanding how to break things down by state where needed.

For example, take Canada.  There are a few big Provinces like Ontario, Alberta.

I just happen to sort of know that.  But how can I get to know such information about other countries like Mexico or Russia, etc.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 4):

It depends what do you define as a "code". An abbreviation?

The ISO breaks down the geopolitical world into only [country codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1). Beyond that, <s>there are no international standards for a country's regions</s> (e.g., State, Province, Territory, Region, District, etc.). **Update**: The ISO also defines principle subdivisions of countries with [ISO 3166-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2).

The US Federal Gov't has a [Federal Information Processing Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Information_Processing_Standard), which defines [country codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIPS_country_codes) and [region codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIPS_region_codes). However, I've never heard Ontario being referred to as `CA08`, so I'm not convinced this would be helpful. Plus it appears there are some missing holes, like "[*Note: Tasman Region was not assigned a code for unknown reasons*.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIPS_region_codes_%28M%E2%80%93O%29#NZ%3a_New_Zealand)"

Comment: As a side note, the Wikipedia article about the [Tasman Region](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tasman_Region) mentions that the Tasman and [Nelson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson,_New_Zealand) regions are often grouped together.

Answer (score 1):

For Canada and all details including Provinces ( & FIPS Code):

```
http://api.geonames.org/search?q=Canada&maxRows=10&lang=en&username=demo&style=full
```

prettified: 
http://www.geonames.org/CA/administrative-division-canada.html

Answer (score 0):

For Canada, you can use GeoBase : http://www.geobase.ca/. You can download a shapefile Administrative Boundary